# JMX MXBean proxy InvalidObjectException

Tags: java, jmx

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

my com.intel.esg.ecp.cli.Command connected to JMX, and find the MXBean com.acme.AcmeManager, it supposes to call createObject to create AcmeObject.

Both AcmeManager and AcmeObject are designed to be MXBean, and I published the without issue.

Does the stack mean the AcmeObject doesn't confirm the MXBean standard or AcmeManager doesn't confirm the MXBean standard?
I am new to JMX MXBean, and can someone points me some useful materials?

Thanks

```
Executing 'createObject' ...
ERROR: Cannot make MXBean proxy for com.acme.AcmeManager: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Do not know how to make a com.acme.Acme from a CompositeData: no method from(CompositeData); no constructor has @ConstructorProperties  
annotation; does not have a public no-arg constructor; contains methods other than getters (getStatus)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot make MXBean proxy for com.acme.AcmeManager: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Do not know how to make a com.acme.AcmeObject from a CompositeData: no method from(CompositeData); no 
constructor has @ConstructorProperties annotation; does not have a public no-arg constructor; contains methods other than getters (getStatus)
        at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.findMXBeanProxy(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:323)
        at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:247)
        at $Proxy18.createObject(Unknown Source)
        at com.acme.cli.commands.tenant.CreateTenantCommand.implExecute(CreateTenantCommand.java:71)
        at com.intel.esg.ecp.cli.Command.execute(Command.java:64)
        at com.intel.esg.ecp.cli.CLI.execute(CLI.java:332)
        at com.acme.cli.commands.Main.main(Main.java:174)

Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Do not know how to make a com.acme.AcmeObject from a CompositeData: no method from(CompositeData); no constructor has @ConstructorProperties annotation; does not have a public no-arg   
constructor; contains methods other than getters (getStatus)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.invalidObjectException(OpenConverter.java:1403)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.makeCompositeBuilder(OpenConverter.java:891)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.checkReconstructible(OpenConverter.java:897)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CollectionConverter.checkReconstructible(OpenConverter.java:663)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.checkCallToOpen(ConvertingMethod.java:94)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$Visitor.visitAttribute(MXBeanProxy.java:53)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$Visitor.visitAttribute(MXBeanProxy.java:48)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanAnalyzer.visit(MBeanAnalyzer.java:53)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.<init>(MXBeanProxy.java:45)
        at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.findMXBeanProxy(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:319)
        ... 6 more
~>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> The MXBean concept provides a simple way to code an MBean that only
>   references a predefined set of types, the ones defined by
>   javax.management.openmbean. In this way, you can be sure that your
>   MBean will be usable by any client, including remote clients, without
>   any requirement that the client have access to model-specific classes
>   representing the types of  your MBeans.

Clearly, **com.acme.Acme** and **com.acme.AcmeObject** are custom types and they don't define the conversion to/from opendata types. See the [OpenData type mapping rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html#mapping-rules) for more information.